# Fusion Tables Layer datapoints

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am implementing Fusion Tables Layer Google Maps in Asp.Net(C#) web application.
To initialize FusionTablesLayer object, the datapoints can be given in to form of an array or table id is compulsory, if table id is compulsory, then how to share it to use with google API, sharing table is free or it is paid service?

Can anybody help me out for solving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sharing tables is free, but when you want to use them together with FusionTablesLayer they must be shared  as **public** or **unlisted**

Comment: Hello Dr. Molle, Thanks for the response. I am trying to create a fusion table after signing in into google account, I am using "CREATE A FUSION TABLE" option for this, but it says "you do not have access to this service",how to share the table?

Thanks.

Comment: You must activate the service **Fusion Tables API** in the [developer-console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Comment: Hello Dr. Molle, Thanks for the response again.I have tried to activate the service from "Explore this API" option, if i check manage, view options then at the moment it grants authorization, but when I reopen this page, it disables the authorization & it does not permit me for creating a fusion table too as mentioned above.

Comment: When you use the API-explorer(I guess so): you'll need to refresh authorization there each time you load the explorer(it's not sufficient to be logged in). The API-explorer is intended to test APIs/methods, when you want to create a FusionTable(manually) do it at https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?dsrcid=implicit

Comment: Hello Dr. Molle, Thanks for the response again.....I have tried the way you have mentioned, I have granted Manage Fusion Tables option......In "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:", it shows ON, then when I try to create fusion table using the url you have mentioned, it does not allow me, & when I refresh the api explorer page, it shows me OFF in "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:"